# How to run timer on separate thread

Tags: c#

I have need to make a splash screen with a progress bar. My problem is that I cannot link the main form with the splash screen:

```
public LogIn_Form() {
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashStart));
    t.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    InitializeComponent();
    t.Abort();
}

public void SplashStart() {
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Where I have "Application.Run(new Form1());" it gives me an error under Form1.

This is the splash screen form:

```
public SplashScreen_Form() {
    InitializeComponent();
    timer.Start();
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Opacity += 0.07;

    pbrLoad.Increment(1);
    if (pbrLoad.Value == 100) 
        timer.Stop();
}

private void SplashScreen_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Opacity = 0;
    timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Now I need to keep it like that but with no errors.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Using `Thread.Abort()` is a very bad thing to do. The entire thing is very oddly designed, I recommend using a custom [`ApplicationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157901%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that starts your splash screen and your main form instead of starting each one separately and not create any extra threads at all.

Comment: The UI exists in one thread you should not attempt to interact with it from another. You also shouldn't be using `Thread.Abort()`.

Comment: Can you post a code sample for me?